# BigQuery convert unix timestamp struct to struct of datetime

Tags: struct, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table that contains a struct column called `daySliderTimes` in the following form:

`daySliderTimes STRUCT<_field_1 STRUCT<_seconds INT, _nanoseconds INT>, _field_1 STRUCT<_seconds INT, _nanoseconds INT>`.

`_field_1` and `_field_2` represent two different timestamps. `_seconds` and `_nanoseconds` represent time since the unix epoch.

I want to convert the data into a new `STRUCT` with the following form:

`daySlidertimes STRUCT<startTime DATETIME, endTime DATETIME>`

This is the table as seen in the BigQuery UI:

[image]

Comment: You can use **TIMESTAMP_SECONDS()** function. This function converts the seconds in a unix format to DATETIME. Therefore, you are able to transform _daySliderTimes._field_1.seconds_ to a date format with the syntax _TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(daySliderTimes._field_1.seconds)_ as well as for __field_2_, then aggregate them in a new struct.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new table from the old one with the format `daySlidertimes STRUCT<startTime DATETIME, endTime DATETIME>`, you can cast the data in milliseconds and so then transform it to TIMESTAMP with the function "TIMESTAMP_MICROS", check this link to see the amount of functions to parse timestamp [1].

An example of the query should look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `project.dataset.new_table` AS 
   SELECT searchDocId, 
   STRUCT(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(CAST( 
   ((daySliderTimes.field1.seconds * 1e+6)  + 
   ROUND(daySliderTimes.field1.nanoseconds * 0.001)) AS INT64)) as 
   startTime, 
   TIMESTAMP_MICROS(CAST( ((daySliderTimes.field2.seconds * 1e+6)  + 
   ROUND(daySliderTimes.field2.nanoseconds * 0.001)) AS INT64)) as endTime) 
   as daySliderTimes, 
   enabledDaySliders
FROM `project.dataset.old_table`
```

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#parse_timestamp

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TIMESTAMP_SECONDS()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#timestamp_seconds) function. This function converts the seconds to **DATETIME** format.

Therefore, you are ale to transform ***daySliderTimes._field_1.seconds*** to a date using **TIMESTAMP_SECONDS()** function. As well as, for ***_field_2***, then aggregate them in a new struct format.

During the creation of the view or table, in your select you can do the following:

```
WITH table_newStruct as(
  SELECT 
#Select all the desired fields
         searchDocId,
         STRUCT(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(daySliderTimes._field_1.seconds) as startTime, 
         TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(daySliderTimes._field_.seconds) as endTime) as new_daySlidertimes

FROM 'table_source')

SELECT searchDocId, new_daySlidertimes 
FROM 'table_newStruct'
```

In addition, the returned *TIMESTAMP* should be in the following format *1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC*. You can format it using the [FORMAT_DATE()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#format_date) function.